# Deeplink in Ionic V4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

We are using Ionic 4 with lazy loading. My app routing works by app.routing.module.ts file. How to use deep link to open app from external link like email or sms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you didn't type this into Google first so this question is likely going to be closed shortly.

Ionic provide a deep linking library:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks

It's used like this:

```
this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.navController, {
  '/about-us': AboutPage,
  '/products/:productId': ProductPage
}).subscribe(match => {
    // match.$route - the route we matched, which is the matched entry from the arguments to route()
    // match.$args - the args passed in the link
    // match.$link - the full link data
    console.log('Successfully matched route', match);
  }, nomatch => {
    // nomatch.$link - the full link data
    console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match', nomatch);
  });
```

You are supposed to do as much research as you can on your own before you open a question on StackOverflow. People are happy to help but they usually want to see you have tried for yourself as you are just giving your job to somebody else otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not post my question directly I first google it and then i did not find any solution then only i posted it.I have already tried this. I am using lazy loading also . When i used the above mention code then i got error like this - navController.push is not defined

Comment: ok fair enough, I was just explaining the rules of stackoverflow. You need to put this in your question, explain it so it's simple for people to understand what you are stuck with, post some code, hopefully they will be able to help.

Comment: the navController is something you need to import into the page, if you follow to the native docs I linked, there is an ionic2 repo that has an example, you could try that for more info, or try searching github for code examples

Comment: seems [this repo](https://github.com/pango-tz/pango-rent/blob/67e7398f41f696b870c75c9316a2fe4297e729cc/src/app/app.component.ts) might get you moving in the right direction

Comment: The issue is - all documentation is outdated and as with your answer only provides answers for Ionic 1 and Ionic 2. The question specifically requests assistance with V4 & lazy loading. Deeplinking on Ionic4 seems to be pretty obscure in documentation. I know Universal Links are required both in profile and in config - but beyond that, how to integrate it within your app is a mystery on Google & Ionic resources alike.